# Git shows uncommitted changes even after committing all changes and reopening Xcode - Git Tower

Tags: ios, xcode, git, git-tower

I have an Xcode project where I'm using `Git`(Git Tower) as my version control, my issue is that  `Git Tower`show uncommitted changes even after, committing all changes, closing the Xcode project and reopening it.

In other words, If I cleaned up my Staging area by committing all changes, then close the `Xcode project`; at this point, nothing has changed, the staging area is cleaned, but as soon as I re-open the `Xcode project`, `Git Tower` shows uncommitted changes in some `.storyboard` files without me doing anything to the views.

Any idea why `Git` shows uncommitted changes for some `.storyboard` files without me modifying anything, what is generating those changes in Xcode?

#### For instance, these changes showed up after committing all changes and reopening the project in Xcode.

[image]

## EDIT:

My main question is why am I seeing uncommitted changes without me modifying anything, what is generating these changes in Xcode?

Comment: Should .storyboard file be mentioned in .gitignore?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, I kind of like to keep track of changes in the `.storyboards`. I'm not sure what's typically done.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to mark the file as "Assume Unchanged".

You can find more information on this in the Tower Help guide:

> There might be cases when you want to modify a file but not have these modifications committed to the repository. And, since this file might be already tracked, you cannot or don't want to ignore it.
>   This is when Git's "assume-unchanged" flag comes in handy. You can mark a file with this flag and thereby have Git ignore local changes for it.
>
> In Tower, you can achieve this by right-clicking the file and selecting Set Assume-Unchanged from the Mark submenu.

For more info on the difference between Ignoring a file and marking it as "Assume Unchanged" see our Help: https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/working-copy/ignore-files